# Jquery Different behaviour of $("document").ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery .bind() and/or .ready() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195169/jquery-bind-and-or-ready-not-working)

Why is there a difference in o/p between the below similar programs?

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
 <script>
   function main()
   {
    $("#inside").text("1234");
   }
   $(document).ready( function(){
       main();   // 1
    });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="inside">abcd</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

> **Output:1234**

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
 <script>
   function main()
   {
    $("#inside").text("1234");
   }
   $(document).ready( main());//2
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="inside">
    abcd
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

> **Output : abcd**

Why does the innerHTML not change here?  Kindly Explain this behavior.. :)

Comment: Please, someone, close as a duplicate...

Comment: @pst - Why don't you get the ball rolling on that?

Comment: @jmort253 It's hard to find duplicates with such "useful" titles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second variation, you're calling `document.ready` for the *result* of the function. To call it for the function itself, just omit the parentheses:

```
$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second version, you are invoking the `main()` function immediately, rather than passing it as a callback - what you're passing to `$(document).ready()` is actual the result of the `main` function, not the function itself.